# Retrieve operational attributes from OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've been having trouble trying to find some good documentation on how to retrieve operational attributes from OpenLDAP.

I would like to retrieve the base distinguished name of an LDAP server by doing an LDAP search.

How come my search doesn't work when I explicitly ask for namingContexts attribute? I've been told that I need to add a plus ('+') sign to the attribute list.

If this is the case, should I get rid of the "namingContexts" attribute or have both?

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.mydomain.com -x -s base -b "" +
# note the + returns operational attributes
```

**Edit:** Note how it looks like the attributes requested are empty. Shouldn't the plus sign be in the attribute list? http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/#operational

reference: [plus sign operator with OpenLDAP](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/ldap+system+administration/Part+I+LDAP+Basics/Chapter+4.+OpenLDAP+Building+a+Company+White+Pages/4.5+Adding+the+Initial+Directory+Entries/)

Comment: I just tried doing
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.mydomain.com -x -s base -b "" namingContexts on a sun directory server and it worked, so you're probably doing the right thing. The '+' didn't change anything. Is it possible you need to authenticate first?

Comment: The plus sign should be specific for OpenLDAP.

Comment: What version of OpenLDAP are you using? What does "doesn't work" mean precisely? What is the output when you run that command? I ran it on my OpenLDAP instance and it produced output similar to carrell's. I'm wondering if it may be a permissions issue. Perhaps anonymous users don't have read access on dn="" or access to the operational attributes in question?

Answer (score 5):

> How come my search doesn't work when I explicitly ask for namingContexts attribute?

What is not working?  Do you recieve an error?

When there is a plus sign it returns all the attributes, regardless if namingContexts is added.

Using:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.example.com -s base -b "" namingContexts
```

Returns:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContexts 
#

#
dn:
namingContexts: o=example.com

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

It is also listed using:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.example.com -s base -b "" +
```

Returning:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: + 
#

#
dn:
structuralObjectClass: OpenLDAProotDSE
namingContexts: o=example.com
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.18
supportedControl: 2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2
supportedControl: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.10.1
supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1413
supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1339
supportedControl: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319
supportedControl: 1.2.826.0.1.334810.2.3
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.1
supportedExtension: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.1
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.2
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.3
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.4
supportedFeatures: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.5.5
supportedLDAPVersion: 2
supportedLDAPVersion: 3
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First access rule in my slapd.conf is explicitly to make sure that this is permitted; make sure you have something similar:

```
# Let all clients figure out what auth mechanisms are available, determine
# that TLS is okay, etc
access to dn.base=""
        by *            read
```